# ggplot with multiple flags

Tags: r, ggplot2, flags

I have a basic data set that includes several flags:

```
library(ggplot2)
X<-c(seq(1:10))
Y<-c(2,4,6,3,5,8,6,5,4,3)
Flag1<-c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)
Flag2<-c(0,0,0,0,60,0,0,0,0,60)
Flag3<-c(12,0,12,12,12,12,12,0,0,12)
Flag4<-c(0,0,0,0,40,0,0,40,0,0)

DF<-data.frame(X,Y,Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4)
```

Each Flag Type (1-4) contains either a "0", or a number specific to that flag type. My goal is to plot the above x/y data as a basic line plot

```
p<-ggplot(DF, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +geom_line() +geom_point(col='black', size=1)
```

But than overlay points on the plot to mark where I have flags. Ideally the flag points would be slightly larger, and each Flag type would be a different color.

Some of my flag points will overlap, so I'm not sure what is the most aesthetically pleasing way to deal with that (maybe an offset to keep the points from overlapping?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reshaping the data from wide to long, *i.e.* create columns for flag type and flag value. Then you can colour by flag type and use `size` for flag value. One way to avoid overlap is `geom_jitter`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
DF %>% 
gather(flag, value, -X, -Y) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(X, Y)) + geom_line() + geom_jitter(aes(color = flag, size = value))
```

Result:
[image]

Another alternative is to use `facet_grid` for separate plots by flag type.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

X<-c(seq(1:10))
Y<-c(2,4,6,3,5,8,6,5,4,3)
Flag1<-c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)
Flag2<-c(0,0,0,0,60,0,0,0,0,60)
Flag3<-c(12,0,12,12,12,12,12,0,0,12)
Flag4<-c(0,0,0,0,40,0,0,40,0,0)

DF<-data.frame(X,Y,Flag1,Flag2,Flag3,Flag4)

DF.long <- melt(DF, measure.vars=c("Flag1","Flag2","Flag3","Flag4"), variable="Flag")
```

So that the data is organized with a single column for flag type, and a single column for its corresponding value, i.e.:

```
X Y     Flag value
1 2    Flag1     0
2 4    Flag1     0
3 6    Flag1     0
4 3    Flag1     0
5 5    Flag1     1
6 8    Flag1     0
7 6    Flag1     0
8 5    Flag1     1
9 4    Flag1     0
0 3    Flag1     0
1 2    Flag2     0
2 4    Flag2     0
3 6    Flag2     0
4 3    Flag2     0
5 5    Flag2    60
...etc
```

It can then be plotted as follows:

```
p <- ggplot(DF.long, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +geom_line() +geom_jitter(size=2, aes(y=value, color=Flag))
```

geom_line() will inherit the X and Y from the original ggplot() call, and geom_jitter() is set to have its own distinct value for y (the column named "value" in the above example), with a unique color for each flag:

[image]

Edit: Ahhh, values as a size corresponding to the value, that would in fact be much more intuitive, and I misunderstood ;)

as in the suggestion by neilfws, use size=value:

```
p2 <-ggplot(DF.long, aes(x=X, y=Y)) +geom_line() +geom_jitter(aes(size=value, color=Flag))
```